# Any (array) comparison does not work

Tags: postgresql

I had a table1 (id - unique)

```
|---|----------|
|id | array    |
|---|----------|
|0  | [2, 4, 6]|
|1  | [3, 5, 1]|
|---|----------|
```

and table2

```
|---|----|
|id |val |
|---|----|
|1  | 23 |
|2  | 34 |
|3  | 19 |
|4  | 61 |
|5  | 47 |
|6  | 3  |
|---|----|
```

I don't now how to make a request like this:

```
 SELECT val FROM table2 WHERE id = ANY(SELECT array FROM table1 WHERE id = 1)
```

### Edit

Or simpler this does not work:

```
select 2 = any (select array[2, 4]);
ERROR:  operator does not exist: integer = integer[]
LINE 1: select 2 = any (select array[2, 4]);
                 ^
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

While this works:

```
select 2 = any ((select array[2, 4])::int[]);
 ?column?
----------
 t
```

Comment: `select 2 = any (array[2, 4]);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1)

```
SELECT val FROM table2
WHERE id = ANY((SELECT array FROM table1 WHERE id = 1)::int[])
```

2)

```
SELECT val FROM table2 
WHERE ARRAY[id] <@ (SELECT array FROM table1 WHERE id = 1)
```

3)

```
SELECT val FROM table2
WHERE id in (SELECT unnest(array) FROM table1 WHERE id = 1)
```

4)

```
SELECT val FROM table2
WHERE exists (SELECT 1 FROM table1 WHERE id = 1 and table2.id = ANY(array))
```

5) As you can see there are a lot of possibilities ;)